# Adjust suspend timer Ubuntu 20.04 server with command line

Tags: server, suspend

My server keeps putting it's self to sleep when I'm watching PLEX and I'm not sure how to fix this

I've tried to search for ways to adjust the sleep settings but nobody seems to have the same question

I don't want to disable suspend because I don't use the server 24/7 it stays mostly unused.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you sure you're running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS?  and not a desktop release?  If you've added a desktop to a server system; you've turned your box into a desktop system & need to reverse the power savings options (default for desktop; turned off for servers) - but suspend is abnormal for a server install

Comment: One option might be to disable the sleep function between certain hours of the day, allowing the machine to stay on for the hours that you actually use it 